# Do I need to wash the flax and sesame seeds before grinding them?

Tags: seeds, flax

I have [a bag of flax seeds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IBSZL56) and [a bag of sesame seeds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GT03JJ8) from Food to Live at  Amazon. I want to grind them in a coffee grinder, and eat their powder.

For food safety and health consideration and best absorption,

- are the seeds ready to eat from the bag?
- Do I need to wash them before or after grinding them? If yes, how?
- Do I need to cook them before or after grinding them? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're all ready to eat.

Washing them is just going to get them wet, and it'll be difficult to impossible (especially for the flax) to get them dry enough to grind to a powder.

People *do* sometimes soak flax seeds, or mix ground flax seeds with water, in order to get something to use as a vegan egg substitute, but I don't think that's what you're going for.

Comment: thanks. After grinding the seeds and pour the powder out, there is still a lot of powder stick to the inner face of the grinder, and I don't have a tool to empty. Is it acceptable to unplug the grinder, pour some drinking water inside the grinder and then let the water and powder flow out together, and then I drink it?

Comment: I don't know whether your grinder is okay to pour water in. But I'd try to scrape out by hand or with a spoon before I'd try water; that's just going to make it even more of a mess. The powder isn't going to dissolve, it'll likely clump and stick to the grinder.

Comment: I keep an inch-wide paintbrush within easy reach of my spice grinder to clean it out.  If stuff is *really* sticking to the side, you can scrape them down with a butter knife or a spoon, run a tablespoon of salt through the grinder, dump it out, brush it out, and repeat.